# How to stop double click event or opening child node when clicking on parent node in jsTree?

Tags: jstree

Here is the JavaScript code to prevent the double click event

```
$("#jstree_view").on("dblclick", 'li a', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 13):

set the $.jstree.defaults.core.dblclick_toggle = false

example:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    "core" : {
         "dblclick_toggle" : false
     }
});
```

[jstree API](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=dblclick_toggle&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.dblclick_toggle)